# Ubuntu 21.04 cannot boot up , Black screen comes after sleep

Tags: ubuntu

I recently upgrade from ubuntu 20.10 to 21.04 and now I am facing issues related to boot.
The computer cannot boot up after the lock screen and it gets stuck when computer is kept without working for sometime

Comment: Sounds like your computer might be going to sleep and not waking up.

Comment: No. I configure the settings to keep it on always. That's the only way I could fix it.